# How can I print onetime data from pivot table Laravel (Laravel 8)

Tags: laravel, loops

I need help

In a foreach loop I access to a pivot table but when I need print that information one time

```
            @foreach ($autoevaluacion as $dato)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$dato->nombre}}</td>
                    @foreach ($dato->encuesta_desempenio as $rta) 
                        <td>{{json_decode($rta->pivot->evaluado)[0]}}</td>
                        <td>{{$rta->pivot->respuesta}}</td>  
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

json_decode($rta->pivot->evaluado)[0] this I don't need repeat, how i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add if condition like below

```
  @foreach ($autoevaluacion as $dato)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$dato->nombre}}</td>
                    @foreach ($dato->encuesta_desempenio as $key=>$rta) 
                        @if($loop->first)
                        <td>{{json_decode($rta->pivot->evaluado)[0]}}</td>
                       @endif                        
                         <td>{{$rta->pivot->respuesta}}</td>  
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```